# In c#, check to see if another.msi and.exe installation is active

Tags: c#

Before beginning to install the MSI application in C# code, I wanted to see whether any other.msi and.exe installs were already in progress. whether so, we can stop them or wait until they are finished before continuing to install our programme component.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049193/how-to-prevent-msi-error-another-program-is-being-installed

Comment: Use the `Installer` object from the **WindowsInstaller** namespace to get the product code of the MSI file. Then loop through all running processes and check if any of them are Windows Installer processes installing the same product. If a matching process is found, wait for it to finish before continuing with the installation. Finally, start the installation process using the `Process.Start()` method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140820/how-do-i-test-if-another-installation-is-already-in-progress